# ESLint: PayloadAction not found in '@reduxjs/toolkit'(import/named)

Tags: react-redux, eslint, node-modules, importerror

I'm currently building a React app with Redux-toolkit on TypeScript, which was created using  create-react-app & I'm getting this error in every Reducer file in my project:

**ESLint: PayloadAction not found in '@reduxjs/toolkit'(import/named)**

Here is one described for example

Code:

```js
import {createSlice, PayloadAction} from "@reduxjs/toolkit" // An error is coming from here

export interface IInitialState {
    isDisSignUp: boolean
}

const initialState: IInitialState = {
    isDisSignUp: true,
}

export const buttonSlice = createSlice({
    name: "button",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        disSignUpButton(state, action: PayloadAction<boolean>) {
            state.isDisSignUp = action.payload
        },
    },
})

export default buttonSlice.reducer
```

My .eslintrc.json

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:import/recommended",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "modules": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module",
        "project": "tsconfig.json"
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "react-hooks", "import"],
    "rules": {
        "indent": [
            "error",
            4,
            {
                "SwitchCase": 1
            }
        ],
        "linebreak-style": ["error", "unix"],
        "quotes": ["error", "double"],
        "semi": ["error", "never"],
        "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
            1,
            {
                "extensions": [".tsx"]
            }
        ],
        "import/prefer-default-export": "off",
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "ignorePackages",
            {
                "ts": "never",
                "tsx": "never"
            }
        ]
    },
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "extensions": [".jsx", ".js", ".ts", ".tsx"]
            },
            "typescript": {
                "alwaysTryTypes": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My .tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```

My package.json

```json
{
    "name": "test_task__myself2",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.3",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
        "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
        "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.7",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.7",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "classnames": "^2.3.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
        "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.2.0",
        "sass": "^1.54.0",
        "typescript": "^4.4.2",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^7.2.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4",
        "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2"
    }
}
```

**Edit**

This solution helped me:

Edit .eslintrc.json

```json
    "settings": {
        "import/parsers": {
            "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
        },
        "import/resolver": {
            "typescript": {
                "alwaysTryTypes": true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @alibdeir I've had to import it the same as this [answer](/a/73895904/8690857) in the TS projects I've used RTK in. Why would it be different elsewhere or for you?

Comment: @DrewReese Very weird. I always just relied on VSCode's auto-imports, and it seemed to work without the "type" keyword

Answer (score 8):

Try :

```
    import type {PayloadAction} from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, it worked for me

```js
import {createSlice, PayloadAction} from "toolkit"
```

If this doesn't work, try editing some parts of file to this:

```json
"settings": {
    "import/parsers": {
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
        "typescript": {
            "alwaysTryTypes": true
        }
    }
}
```